# Integer coefficients in a polynomial function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, integers

The problem:

> Find the polynomial $r(x)$ with the smallest degree and integer coefficients s.t. it has zeroes -1, 2/3 and -2 w/ resp multiplicities 2, 8 and 4 and $r(1) = -1$.

---

What I tried:

Without the integer coefficients and $r(1) = -1$ constraints, I think we can have:

$$r(x) = (x+1)^2(x-2/3)^8(x+2)^4$$

With the $r(1) = -1$ constraint, we must find either of the following

1. a suitable $a$:

$$r(x) = a(x+1)^2(x-2/3)^8(x+2)^4$$

2. a suitable $b$:

$$r(x) = (x+1)^2(x-2/3)^8(x+2)^4 + b$$

As for the integer coefficient constraint, I kind of have a feeling that that dictates which of the above we should choose. Does it? Where exactly does the integer coefficient constraint come in?

I guess without the $r(1) = -1$ constraint but with the integer coefficient constraint, we could have:

$$r(x) = \frac{1}{3^8}(x+1)^2(3x-2)^8(x+2)^4$$

Wait that doesn't really satisfy the integer coefficient constraint does it?

Okay so I don't know. How do I satisfy both the integer coefficients and $r(1) = -1$ constraints?

Comment: In case 2. $r(-1) = b$, $-1$ should be a zero.

Comment: Adding $b$ will ruin our roots, so this is out of question. As for the integer coefficients constraint, just ignore it until you have the answer. Find that $a$, then see where it gets you.

Comment: @Abstraction Ah thanks. So it's really just case 1 then?

Comment: @IvanNeretin If roots were the only constraints... obviously, $r(x)=q(x)(x+1)^2(3x-2)^8(x+2)^4$, but $q(1)=-{1 \over 2^2*3^4}$ with integer coefficients of $r$ seems impossible. Can't figure out a strict proof, though.

Comment: @Abstraction smallest degree so $q(x)$ is constant?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I found a. Where does that get me? :|

Comment: Well... let me see. You have the right roots and the right value at 1, but the coefficients are not quite integer. Can you multiply this thing by any number? No, that would ruin the value at 1. Add something? No, that would change the roots. It seems we're out of luck.

Comment: omg. this is a problem in a sample long test in a precalculus class. well thanks @IvanNeretin  :)) it was probably typo in the exam. damn integer coefficient requirement. this isn't a number theory class. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $r(x)$ meeting the required conditions.

Suppose there was. Clearly its coefficients would have gcd 1 (because $r(1)=-1$), so it would be "primitive". By Gauss polynomial lemma, $(3x-2)^8$ must be a factor of $r(x)$. Similarly $(x+1)^2$ and $(x+2)^4$. Hence we must be able to write it as $q(x)(x+1)^2(3x-2)^8(x+2)^4$ where $q(x)$ has integer coefficients. But then $r(1)=-1$ implies $q(1)=-\frac{1}{324}$, which is impossible.

To spell out the first step in more detail: the lemma states that if $r(x)$ is a (non-constant) primitive polynomial with integer coefficients which is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is also reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. We know that $r(x)$ has the factor $(x-\frac{2}{3})^8$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, so we keep taking out factors until we are forced to take out that factor in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as $(3x-2)^8$.

Comment: omg. this is a problem in a sample long test in a precalculus class. well thanks almagest :)) it was probably typo in the exam. damn integer coefficient requirement. this isn't a number theory class. :|